# Why there is no horizontal scrollbar for select in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, drop-down-menu, scrollbar

Why there is no horizontal scrollbar in FireFox for such select?

```
<select style="width: 100px; overflow:auto;" size="10">
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
    <option>some long text to make it scroll</option>
</select>
```

It works in Chrome just perfect
http://jsfiddle.net/r4gnLymr/

Comment: Hmmm that's weird, but why do you want to render your list like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontal scrollbar not working on select tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176901/horizontal-scrollbar-not-working-on-select-tag)

Comment: possible duplicate of [horizontal scroll bar in select box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917824/horizontal-scroll-bar-in-select-box)

Comment: Which version of FireFox you use ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917824/horizontal-scroll-bar-in-select-box

Comment: I don't see any `horizontal scrollbar` on _chrome 33_!

Comment: If you check _computed styles_ in both browsers, you'll see that Chrome is adding `overflow: visible` to both x and y axis, while FF adds `overflow: auto;` with `overflow: -moz-scrollbars-horizontal;`?

Answer (score 3):

```css
div{   
 overflow-x:auto;
 overflow-y:auto;   
 }
```

```html
<div style="width:140px;">
    <select name="selectbox" size="5"  id="selectbox" >
        <option value="1">one two three four five six seven eight</option>
        <option value="2">seven eight</option>
        <option value="3">nine ten</option>
        <option value="1">one two three four five six</option>
        <option value="2">seven eight</option>
        <option value="3">nine ten</option>
        <option value="1">one two three four five six</option>
        <option value="2">seven eight</option>
        <option value="3">nine ten</option>
        <option value="1">one two three four five six</option>
        <option value="2">seven eight</option>
        <option value="3">nine ten</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This one is from [Select box html horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250724/select-box-html-horizontal-scroll) and show the horizontal scrollbar.